# Open folder or create folder if doesn't exist with different constant parent folder can be on 3 different path

Tags: ms-access, path, vba, constants

I have a code to create folder or open folder if exist which works completely fine. 
Now my only problem is that there can be 3 users of this database and the 3 users has individual parent folder path. They all use and share all the folders in the parent folder and has the same parent folder name, only the path is different for the parent folder.
My existing code as follows:

```
Private Sub Command299_Click()
Const strParent = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Jobs\"
Dim strJobID As String
Dim strClient As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim fso As Object
' Create FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Get year from control - modify as needed
strClient = "(" & Me.[Client ID] & ") " & [Client Name]
' Path with year
strFolder = strParent & strClient
' Check whether folder exists
If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
    ' If not, create it
    fso.CreateFolder strFolder
End If
' Get student ID from control
strJobID = Me.[Job ID] & " " & [Job name]
' Full path
strFolder = strFolder & "\" & strJobID
' Check whether folder exists
If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
    ' If not, create it
    fso.CreateFolder strFolder
End If
' Open it
Shell "explorer.exe " & strFolder, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

As I said it does work completely fine on my computer where the const parent folder path is what is in the code, but how can I make this code work for different path?
My 1st idea was to give an "or" statement in the Const line
    Const strParent = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Jobs\"
But it didn't want to work. Is there any way to give 3 constant path for the parent folder and if one of them exists, work from there?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: So the path is via the individual Users folder? Code needs to know who is using the db. Is the Users folder the same name as their network login? No, can't use a constant for the path, at least not past C:\Users\. Build the path dynamically. One way to retrieve user network username is with `Environ(USERNAME)`.

Comment: Correction, expression would be: `Environ("USERNAME")`.

Comment: Yes the path is via the individual user. The database is shared between 3 computers, the main Job folder is also shared between 3 computer, but the path to the Job folder is different on all computers. How to build the path dynamically? . I was also thinking to somehow code in a search function first for the Job folder to get the path on each computer, or maybe save the database in the main folder I think there is a code to get to the folder where the database saved in whatever is the path of it

Comment: You could have them run the application from the specified folder and use the `Application.CurrentProject.Path` parameter to build the full path to the specified folder. For example: `Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Jobs\" & "filename.ext"`

Comment: Thanks for that will I be still able to use the Const strParent part or it's not needed at all and just put     strFolder = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Jobs\" &strClient ?

Comment: No, the Const is not applicable.

Comment: If folders are within Users individual folders, how can they share them? I would never give anyone access to my folders. Why would common folder be within Users folders?

Comment: Thanks for helping, there are 3 users. we all have our own computer. For folder sharing we use OneDrive. The database is shared with OneDrive too. With the OneDrive you get individual path on each computer to the shared folder. This is how is the system built (not by me). I know OneDrive isn't the best, but I'm just working around what we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options:

If you have a file server, move the files there and use \\servername\share

If you don't have a file server, have one user share the folder and on all 3 computers, connect to the shared drive using the same letter then use that path for access.

if neither of those appeal to you, create a users table in your database with two fields, username and path.  Use the Environ("USERNAME") to get the username (as above) and put the path they need in another column. lookup with

```
Path = DLookup("fieldUserPath", "tblUsers", "fieldUsername = '" & Environ("USERNAME") & "'")
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I have tried this way, just cannot find the reason why does it take me now to the general "documents" folder.. Here is the code I'm using and I have made the users table with the paths for each user.

Comment: `Private Sub Command487_Click()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strJobID As String
    Dim strClient As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim fso As Object
    strPath = DLookup("UserPath", "Users", "Username = '" & Environ("USERNAME") & "'")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strClient = "(" & Me.[Client ID] & ") " & [Client Name]
    strFolder = strPath & strClient`

Comment: `If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder strFolder
    End If
    strJobID = Me.[Job ID] & " " & [Project name]
    strFolder = strFolder & "\" & strJobID
    If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder strFolder
    End If
    Shell "explorer.exe " & strFolder, vbNormalFocus
End Sub`

Comment: And the strangest thing that now even with the original code (see above) it's also takes me to the general Documents folder. What could be happenning?

Comment: Fresh day and all works fine, not too sure what went wrong yesterday :) thank you for all the help